# Cross platform GUI development with C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, cross-platform

Want to know the libraries available for cross platform GUI development(mainly Windows, Mac and Linux). I want to develop an application with majority of **image processing and little bit 3D rendering**.

The app is heavily depends on image files which are very big in size(in Mega Bytes). So I want to make use of **OpenGL** along with the library.

Answer (score 4):

I've used Qt, OpenGL and PCL libraries combined on such projects before without problem. Quick internet search on Qt + OpenGL will give you plenty of resources to investigate if this could work for you.

Comment: Thanks..
But I think Qt doesn't support static linking(as it is LGPL), would be better to use libraries with static linking.

Comment: @startedonnode.js Why? I didn't have any troubles wiith dynamic linking in the past, just you need to make sure that your installer/packages are setup right. Are your other libraries support dynamic linking?

Comment: That's fine. We have used it in the past and are good in this. But for this particular product, our customer has asked us to do not use any dynamic linking libraries like Qt due to some licensing issues.

Comment: @startedonnode.js, why don't you just buy a commercial license for Qt for this project?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL with [Qt](https://qt-project.org/), [TCL/TK](http://www.tcl.tk/) and [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) are some options that you can use. Google about them and decide which suits your needs/expertise.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of size and speed ***FLTK*** is by far your best option. It's a cross-platform GUI library with OpenGL support.

> `Advantages:`
>
> - Extremely *lightweight* comprared to libraries like Qt that take ~ 1GB of space.
> - Fast compilation ~ 5mins compared to Qt's 5 hours compilation.
> - OpenGL / Custom Widget support.
> - Huge documentation + Easy to read source.
> - Compiled statically by default ( no .dlls )
> - A glut-like wrapper for free.
>
> `Disdvantages:`
>
> - Sacrifices features for speed and size.
> - Getting fancy widgets to work is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a look at wxwidgets.
http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/opengl.htm